# Angular 2 dependencies

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

Please consider this dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
                  "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/http": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
                  "@angular/router": "3.2.1",
                  "@angular/upgrade": "2.2.1"
                }
```

I want to use the bundle version of Angulajs and when I run this command:

> npm install angular

It installs `angular.min.js` I want to know what is the difference between Those? Is there any way to bundle dependencies using npm and create a single file?

Another question is I know that `Angular 4` has been released and when I run this command:

> npm install angular

It installs `angular.min.js` with version `v1.6.4` so what is this file? And why it outdated?

Comment: `Angular1` is now known as `AngularJS` while `angular 2 ` is just known as `Angular`. And `angular` is completely rewritten over `angularjs`.

Comment: `Angular2` is incomptaible rewrite of `AngularJS`. When you run `npm install angular` it installs `AngularJS` with latest version being `Angular 1.6.4`. If you want the latest version, you can run `npm install angular-2`. See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44932436/5181313)

Comment: Getting started with Angular2 with CLI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/2814/install-angular2-with-angular-cli#t=201707091709462597615). Getting started without CLI [here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/789/getting-started-with-angular-2/7528/getting-started-with-angular-2-without-angular-cli#t=201707091709462597615)

Comment: Is Angular v4.3.6 is same as Angular 2? I am starting with Mean.io project and want to put angular 2 dependencies only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `npm install angular`, [*AngularJS*](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular) (v1.x) is installed.
Which is why, when you run the command, the latest stable version of *AngularJS* i.e [v1.6.4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#1.6) is installed.
Note: Angular v1 (AngularJS) is still [supported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#Releases). Last stable release was 3 months ago.

---

*Angular* 2 and above versions are simply called [*Angular*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS#Angular_and_AngularDart).
Note: Angular(*v2 or v4*) is an **incompatible rewrite** of AngularJS(*v1*)

---

Now the question is you should choose either of the above according to requirements. The steps you have followed is to get AngularJS(v1).
You can have a look at [Angular Quickstart](https://github.com/angular/quickstart) to get started with Angular2+ which is now updated to v4.4.5 (as of 5th July 2017).
You can have a look at `Package.json` and you would notice,

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/compiler": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/core": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/forms": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/http": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.0.0",
  "@angular/router": "~4.0.0",

  "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
  "systemjs": "0.19.40",
  "core-js": "^2.4.1",
  "rxjs": "5.0.1",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
```

},
which should install current stable version of *Angular*

---

<kbd>angular-cli</kbd> (command-line tool by Angular)

Answer (score 3):

For the second question, you can install Angular 2+ by running this command: `npm install @angular/[package]`. Example:

```
npm install @angular/common@4.1.2 -- installs @angular/common v4.1.2
```

It is also important to note that AngularJS (version 1) is not the same as Angular (version 2+).

Comment: Thanks but what is `common` and what is the difference between it and `angular.min.js`?

Comment: When I ran above command I got this errors: `+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@^5.0.1
+-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY typescript@~2.0.9
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY zone.js@^0.8.4`

Comment: As a footnote if the filename ends in min.js it just means it's been minified. So the Javascript will be sent over the wire faster. it'll be very hard to read.

Comment: i wouldn't use this as a means to download AngularJS, but if you want to see the versions at a glance go to https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/ and see the versions.. 1.6.5 is on there btw...

Answer (score 3):

The big difference in this context is that Angularjs (1.x) gives you one big file, the whole framework and no options. Use just some of it, or even one little bit of it and you have to include it all.

Angular 2 on the other hand is incredibly more modular. Use the things you want, even add your own files and bundle it all together. Since it's using webpack under the hood it's extremely configurable, to the point where you can put your own css and even images in the bundle. How you ask?

`ng build`

This runs webpack which creates a `dist` folder with various script and css-files. Think of this folder as your bundle. Instead of angular.min.js you basically have a `myapp.min.js` which can include everything in your app including angular.

You are probably thinking "But I want only one file!". Sure, you can have it. I think it's going out of your way because the default is actually sensible. One big 5mb js-file including everything is not always the best way. But you can have it!

`ng eject`

This command outputs the webpack configuration to `webpack.config.js`, and any changes you make here will trigger next time you run `ng build` or `ng serve`. It's nothing complicated to have just one file instead of three, but you'll have to study up on webpack yourself though!

Comment: As I understand You said that `angular` is modular. Ok, Where I can find what modules or files I should reference for data binding? HTTP call?

Comment: I think the most useful resource when you are pondering what to import is  [https://angular.io/api](https://angular.io/api) (http is under Http, and NgModel is under Forms)  Many times you don't need two-way data-binding (something I think was actually too easy in angularjs (1.x), why constantly bind two ways when you almost never use data that way?). So the stuff in [templates & data-bindings](https://angular.io/guide/displaying-data) is enough for most things but you can always include ng-model if you need it.

Answer (score 3):

Angular 2 is complete rewrite of angular 1. So I recommend to consider these two as 2 different languages Don't mix the concepts. Angular 2+ is completely modular and spitted into common, compiler, core, http etc . This is done for tree-shaking.

If you want to bundle angular dependencies into one build. use

```
ng eject --force
```

and install [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/)  using

```
npm install -save-dev commons-chunk-plugin
```

then, configure CommonChunkPlugin in webpack.config.js.

To install any angular module use:

```
npm install @angular/[module-name]
```

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend you look into: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli

This is built by the angular team to help people get moving quickly in angular 4.  Many other frameworks do the same thing.  For example react has the same idea with this: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/07/22/create-apps-with-no-configuration.html

This isn't answering your questions directly but you can avoid the complexity involved in setting up angular 4.  In fact that's what the purpose of the angular-cli is, to help people not get stuck spending hours upon hours figuring out what dependencies to install.

Plus, not spend hours upon hours setting up webpack to build an angular project that does a production build.  With angular-cli it's just running the following command:

```
ng build --prod
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Manubhargav](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/162425/xyz) mentioned, when you run `npm install angular`, AngularJS (v1.x) will be installed.

To install the latest version of angular 2 use `npm install angular-2 --save`.
 This command will update the `package.json` and `package-lock.json` files and add `angular-2` dependency to them.

Note: If you got `typings install` error, install it by npm: `npm install typings --global`

To install the latest version of angular 4 you can use one of these 2 methods:

- Using angular CLI:

  1. Install Angular CLI: `npm install -g @angular/cli`
  2. Create a new project: `ng new my-app`
  3. Serve the application: Go to the project directory and launch the server.       `cd my-app
     ng serve --open`
- Manual setup using Seed Project:

  1. Clone seed project from github: `git clone https://github.com/Plum-Crazy/angular-seed`
  2. Run the application: Go to the project directory and launch the server.       `cd angular-seed
     npm install
     npm run`

     Once the project is built, it will be available at http://localhost:3000/